# Android: Saving a bitmap Image

Tags: android, bitmap, save

I have a button that allows the user to save a bitmap image to his/her gallery in a seperate folder after applying modifications on some of pixel bits as shown below

```
Random rand= new Random(TimeZone.LONG);
File root=null;
File file = null;
try{
    root= Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
    file = new File(String.format("%s/IMG_%d.png", root.getCanonicalPath(), Math.abs(rand.nextInt()%100000)));
    FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(file);
    btmImg.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, out);
    MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(getContentResolver(), file.getCanonicalPath(), file.getName(), file.getName());
    out.flush();
    out.close();
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "File is Saved in  " + file, 2000).show();
}
```

The problem is that when I press 'save' button. The image that appears in the user's gallery is not the modified version it is a duplication of the original or something like that. To get the modified version I had to refresh the gallery (by deleting the applications running in the background).

Anyone has an idea about how to solve this !!

Comment: are you sure `btmImg` is the modified version of the bitmap?

Comment: Yes I'm sure. I have called a method that returns Bitmap object and I assigned it to btmImg.